# USB device stuck polling on second call

Tags: linux, usb

I have a scientific camera, a USB3Vision device, that I wrote a program to captures images for. No problems when I use it on my desktop, it works fine every time. If I take the exact same application to another (2 other actually) computer it acquires one image but hangs the second time that you try to capture another.

The desktop I'm developing on is Fedora 25 and I am having this problem on clean installs of both Fedora 24 and 25. Also, on both computers the permissions of the USB device have been set to 666 using a udev rule so it's not some permissions error.

If I attach `gdb` to the process that's hung it shows that it's waiting on a blocking call to `poll()`, I've tried waiting a really long time but it never completes. This is where I'm at a bit of a loss now, I'm not really sure what to poke at to troubleshoot why that call never finishes on computers that aren't the mine. I'm also not really sure how to determine what's different between the USB buses on the different computers, that would probably be really useful too.

Example code to recreate this issue is irrelevant IMO, but here it is because it may be asked for if not included:

```
#include <arv.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    ArvCamera *camera;
    ArvBuffer *buffer;

    camera = arv_camera_new (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : NULL);
    buffer = arv_camera_acquisition (camera, 0);

    if (ARV_IS_BUFFER (buffer))
        printf ("Image successfully acquired\n");
    else
        printf ("Failed to acquire a single image\n");

    g_clear_object (&camera);
    g_clear_object (&buffer);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is just one of the test programs that comes with the Aravis library that works with GenICam type cameras.